# Correct way to apply different functions based on condition in stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface, supplier

What would be the correct way to implement this functional logic with streams?

1. Stream through list of items
2. Check if condition 1 passes, if so apply function 1 to the item.

   Check if condition 2 passes, if so apply function 2 to the item.

   If both conditions do not pass, do nothing.
3. collect results

Do I create predicates with suppliers or how does this look? I'm not very familiar with functional Java.

Comment: What happens when both conditions pass? Also did you attempt to write your code in "normal" non-functional java. I.e. using for-loops and if-statements? From there its sometimes quite easy to convert it to streams

Comment: @Lino Both conditions can't pass, it's logically impossible (its more or less a simple equals). Yes, "normal" code is quite easy -> declare empty array, iterate through items and for each item check condition and add what is returned from function, otherwise iterate over. I could write that, but wanted to see if there is something like this with stream api, as it's always preferred to use that

Comment: *as it's always preferred to use that* -> IMHO you should *never* need to use the Stream API. I don't know where you got that idea. Streams are in 99% of all cases slower than normal loops, have more overhead due to object creation **and** are harder to read. So if you're not *forced* to use streams, just don't.

Comment: That said, you could make use of `Stream.mapMulti` or just something like `map(o -> condition(o) ? mapper.apply(o) : null).filter(o -> o != null)` to implement your problem

Comment: You are checking condition on item. If it is true, you want to apply some function of item ? Are you trying to change item ? And then you want to use same thing again. I think, it is not recommended on stream operation. Supplier applies on terminal operation. I think it should be immutable. And do not use predicate after map operation. At last you can use collect(Collectors.toList) or collect(Collectors.toSet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably best off with a simple for loop, but you could do:

```
List<Item> list;
list.stream()
    .forEach(item -> {
       boolean condition1 = predicate1.test(item);
       boolean condition2 = predicate2.test(item);
       if(condition1 && !condition2) {
            applyFunction1(item);
       } else if(!condition1 && condition2) {
            applyfunction2(item);
       }
   });
```

This operates directly on the underlying list. Use `map` if you want to collect to a different collection (but obviously it depends on the modifying function implementation whether it contains clones or the original, now also modified, objects):

```
List<Item> list;
List<Item> modifiedList = list.stream()
   .map(item -> {
       if(condition1 && !condition2) {
            return function1.apply(item);
       } else if(!condition1 && condition2) {
            return function2.apply(item);
       }
       return item;
   })
   .toList();
```

If you do not care about the final ordering of items, here's another approach, which you can see gets silly...:

```
    List<Item> list;
    Predicate<Item> predicate1;
    Predicate<Item> predicate2;
    Function<Item, Item> function1;
    Function<Item, Item> function2;

    Stream<Item> modifiedBy1 = list.stream()
        .filter(predicate1.and(predicate2.negate()))
        .map(function1);
    Stream<Item> modifiedBy2 = list.stream()
        .filter(predicate1.negate().and(predicate2))
        .map(function1);
    Stream<Item> unmodified = list.stream()
        .filter(predicate1.negate().and(predicate2.negate()));
    
    Stream<Item> recombined = Stream
        .of(modifiedBy1, modifiedBy2, unmodified) //a Stream of Streams
        //you can influence the order of elements by swapping these around
        //the result is essentially sorted by which conditions where matched
        .flatMap(Function.identity()); //flatten the streams back to their constituent objects
    //could also have used 2x Stream.concat here
```

Comment: Yeah, i figured that it might get a bit ugly trying to do this. Went with what i thought was the simplest, using ".map()".